# Friend class 'has no member named...'

Tags: c++, multithreading, friend

My main frame in a wxWidgets project starts a thread when a button is pushed. I tried to use [this example](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread.html) from the documentation of wxThread class, but I get an error compiling it. It says

```
||=== Build: Debug in WindowsDgpsGUI (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\WindowsDgpsGui\NavigationThread.cpp||In destructor 'virtual NavigationThread::~NavigationThread()':|
D:\WindowsDgpsGui\NavigationThread.cpp|82|error: 'class wxFrame' has no member named 'm_navigationThreadCS'|
D:\WindowsDgpsGui\NavigationThread.cpp|84|error: 'class wxFrame' has no member named 'm_navigationThread'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Though I can't find what I did wrong...
This is the code of my main frame:

```
class WindowsDgpsGUIFrame: public wxFrame
{

    public:

        WindowsDgpsGUIFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id = -1);
        virtual ~WindowsDgpsGUIFrame();

    protected:
        wxCriticalSection m_navigationThreadCS; //protects the m_navigationThread pointer

        NavigationThread* m_navigationThread;
        friend class NavigationThread;
}
```

This the header of the thread:

```
class NavigationThread : public wxThread
{

    public:
        /** \name Constructor */
        NavigationThread(wxFrame* parent, navigation_variables usedVariables);

        /** \name Destructor */
        virtual ~NavigationThread();
    private:
        virtual ExitCode Entry();
        wxFrame* m_parent;
}
```

and this the destructor of the thread where the error occurs:

```
NavigationThread::~NavigationThread()
{
     wxCriticalSectionLocker enter(m_parent->m_navigationThreadCS);

     m_parent->m_navigationThread = NULL;
    //dtor
}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `wxFrame` doesn't contain such members, but `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame` does. You might delcare the wrong type for `m_parent`? Shouldn't it be `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame* m_parent;`?

Comment: `m_parent` is a pointer to a `wxFrame` instance, which has none of the wanted members: the derived class `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame` has them. To access the member variables, you may cast `m_parent` to its subtype using `dynamic_cast`, or declare `m_parent` as a `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says: the class `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame` owns a member `m_navigationThreadCS`. The base class `wxThread` doesn't.

You're trying to access the `m_navigationThreadCS` member variable through a `wxThread` pointer

```
NavigationThread::~NavigationThread()
{
     wxCriticalSectionLocker enter(m_parent->m_navigationThreadCS);
                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

since `m_parent` is of type `wxFrame*`, hence your error.

You can either `dynamic_cast` your `m_parent` to the derived class that contains it or just change that type to be `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame*`

Comment: So then I would have to `#include "WindowsDgpsGUIFrame"` in the header, don't I?

Comment: You can declare a pointer to an incomplete type: just forward declare it with a line `class WindowsDgpsGUIFrame;` instead of the `#include`. You will have to include class declaration when using it, usually in your cpp file

Comment: @A.Hue Sorry I misread your comment: yes correct. Either forward declare your class as wasthishelpful said or just include the header altogether.

Comment: But after changing to `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame* m_parent` the error says `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame does not name a type`...So I need the class in the header don't I? So I have to either forward declare it in the header or include it?

Comment: @A.Hue Correct.

Comment: @Marco and if I `#include "WindowsDgpsGUIFrame.h"` there is no such file or directory, so I `#include "WindowsDgpsGUIMain.h"` but then I get an error in the header of `WindowsDgpsGuiFrame` that `NavigationThread` does not name a type, even if it's included...

Comment: All right...I forward declared `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame` in both header and .cpp of NavigationFrame, but now I can't use the `wxCriticalSectionLocker enter(m_parent->m_navigationThreadCS);` part, because of `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class NavigationThread::WindowsDgpsGUIFrame'|`

Comment: @A.Hue Your post doesn't say in which file `WindowsDgpsGUIFrame` is located and I assumed it was in a same-name header. You need to either include that file (and make sure it is in an include path for the compiler to find it) or just [forward declare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) it as wasthishelpful said. Of course the complete type needs to be available at the place where you access stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128607/discussion-between-a-hue-and-marco-a).

Comment: Never mind, I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391401/c-error-invalid-use-of-incomplete-type

Answer (score 0):

So to sum up the comments of the previous answer, this is how it works:

NavigationThread.h:

```
class WindowsDgpsGUIFrame; // Forward declare wxFrame class

/** \brief Class for working thread */
class NavigationThread : public wxThread
{

    public:
        /** \name Constructor */
        NavigationThread(WindowsDgpsGUIFrame* parent, navigation_variables usedVariables);

        /** \name Destructor */
        virtual ~NavigationThread();
}
```

NavigationThread.cpp

```
#include "WindowsDgpsGUIMain.h" // Include main class where frame is placed

NavigationThread::NavigationThread(WindowsDgpsGUIFrame* parent, navigation_variables usedVariables)
{}

NavigationThread::~NavigationThread()
{
     wxCriticalSectionLocker enter(m_parent->m_navigationThreadCS);

     m_parent->m_navigationThread = NULL;
    //dtor
}
```

The main stays the same as in the question.